# Installing acroread without browser plugin

Tags: installation, pdf, browser

The acroread packages includes both the standalone viewer and the browser plugin. I need acroread for some annoying javascript-laced pdfs, but as an everyday viewer I prefer evince. Does anyone know how to install just the standalone viewer in 11.10 Oneiric?

Comment: If you are only concerned about disabling acroread plugins for bowser then (assuming you use firefox). Firefox --> Edit --> Preferences --> (search for pdf) and change value in front of it through dropdown

Comment: there u go :) now its an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only concerned about disabling acroread plugins for your browser then (assuming you use firefox) `Firefox --> Edit --> Preferences --> (search for pdf)` and change value in front of it through the dropdown.

Comment: I want to note that there is a minor bug connected to this: After installation the default setting says "Always Ask", but actually it treats as embedded. One actually needs to switch to "Open with..." and then back to "Always Ask" for firefox to do the right thing.

Comment: Mine worked perfectly from start :-s I never changed the setting and everytime I click on pdf it asks me to save it

Answer (score 0):

You can disable both at the browser and also run

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/*nppdf.so
sudo rm /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/*nppdf.so
sudo rm /usr/lib/firefox/plugins/*nppdf.so
```

to definitely delete the plugin at the system level.

**Warning**: this solution is destructive. Don't run the above commands unless you understand what they mean!