# Disable plugin in Firefox (acroread)

Tags: 11.10, firefox, plugins, adobe, adobe-reader

I installed `acroread` from the repositories, and it has decided it should be the default plugin in Firefox, such that when I click on a pdf, it opens in a Firefox window.  Unfortunately, it does not display (at least when in dual head mode).

This should be simple, but I cannot disable the plugin.  Under Firefox Edit -> Preferences-> Applications -> pdf is set to "always ask" so I don't know why it uses acroread in the first place.  Under Tools -> Manage Content Plugins I see acroread is selected for pdf content.  I have the option in the dropdown to search for a new plugin, but not to simply download the file.

Typing `about:config` into the Firefox toolbar gives me a list of configuration options, but does not mention `plugin.disable` or `acroread` anywhere.

How do I disable the plugin?  I have Firefox 11.0 on Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want to get rid of the plugin permanently, because it is not removed by apt if you remove acroread, you have to delete it manually:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/npwrapper.nppdf.so
```

That worked for me on Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 1):

You go to extensions, and there you can disable:
[image]

Comment: If this is now what you are searching for, I will delete the answer.

Comment: That's it, thanks!  Sounds like the behaviour I described is a known bug, and toggling the Application preferences to `acroread` and then back to `always ask` would work too.  See the comments in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/85421/installing-acroread-without-browser-plugin)

Comment: this issue is ***not*** resolved, as the plugin only seems to be disabled, but effectively is not and the entry will re-appear: cf with this [**unresolved bug**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/731865) for instance...